# Is there a way to check client JavaScript integrity and / or prevent user modification as the server?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I need to have a check on the client side that detects a form of cheating. However, I understand that this can be bypassed by using the browser console, inspect element, or any other modification vector to render the client-sided check inert. My server also has certain checks, but adding a few on the client side would make it much easier to detect certain edge cases. Is there a way to detect people messing with JS code through dev-tools, or should I just stick to a purely server-side approach?

Comment: "should I just stick to a purely server-side approach" - yes.

Comment: If the check is client-side, the user can use DevTools to bypass the checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: "You cannot control, therefore you cannot *trust,* 'the client.'"

**Period.**

Answer (score 0):

You should never trust "the client" and you MUST have checks on the server.

However you can also add the same checks on the frontend site. It will most likely be faster, and it would put less load on the server. It can also improve user experience for the "good" users. Offcourse this approach would lead to more work and have a harder to maintain solution. What was the reason you wanted to have frontend checks?